# What`s the best way to build a login with continuation to a main page after login with React and Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I`m completly new to React and relative new to programing in general.
I have to program a login which routes me to a new page, my main page. The login can be simple with just username or email and a password. The login should be the starting page. And the username/ email and password should be stored in a seperate database where I can check the data from the database while login.

Since this is finished one day, the React application should be transformed into a Electron desktop application.

For now I build a simple login but don`t know where to continue.

What`s the best way to do that? What I should appropriate for this topic? For what topics I should look in general? Do you have any links, tutorials, hints, etc. for doing that?

```js
// LoginForm.js
import React from "react";

export class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { email, password } = this.state; 
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input
          name="email"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your email"
          value={email}                     
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
        <input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter your password"
          value={password}                  
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    );
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    console.log("Submitting");
    console.log(this.state);
  };
}
```

```js
// ValidatedLoginForm.js
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as EmailValidator from "email-validator";
import * as Yup from "yup";
const ValidatedLoginForm = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }} 
    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {  
      setTimeout(() => {                        
        console.log("Logging in", values);
        setSubmitting(false);
      }, 500);
    }}

    validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
      email: Yup.string()
        .email()
        .required("Required"),
      password: Yup.string()
        .required("No password provided.")
        .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
        .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number.")
    })}
  >
    {props => {     
      const {       
        values,
        touched,
        errors,
        isSubmitting,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit
      } = props;    
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            name="email"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your email"
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
          />
          {errors.email && touched.email && (
            <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
          )}
          <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
          <input
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}
          />
          {errors.password && touched.password && (
            <div className="input-feedback">{errors.password}</div>
          )}
          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      );
    }}
  </Formik>
);

export default ValidatedLoginForm;
```

```js
// index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./Login/styles.css";
import ValidatedLoginForm from "./Login/ValidatedLoginForm";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Load Test Admin</h1>
      <ValidatedLoginForm />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
// Einstiegspunkt der Applikation
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You should look for the concepts such as **react-router-dom, protected route (for auth pages)**

The following link can be your way to start
[link](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will look at it directly

Comment: I would appreciate an upvote if this info was beneficial for you